# Could an old, unconfirmed transaction fail to be processed because it is no longer deemed to have enough fees

Tags: transaction-fees

I just read [Why do small transactions without fees ever get processed?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3872/why-do-small-transactions-without-fees-ever-get-processed) and it made me wonder about the risk that a legitimate, lock_timed transaction might not be processed once the lock_time is past.

I'm aware (from the above question) that in the reference implementation, the increasing age of a transaction (in the mempool once it's been submitted?) should increase its priority regardless of the its fees but not every miner is willing to process low(/no) fee transactions even now never mind what they may (not) do in future.

So if I have a signed transaction with a (very!) distant lock_time and it has fees that were considered reasonable at the time that the transaction was created and then when I submit it after lock_time what is the risk that no miners will process it because its fees are *subsequently* considered to be too low to bother with it?

Comment: Is there any way to increase the fees on an already signed transaction?

Comment: No since the signature also signs the outputs (which is how the fee is derived)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that does happen, all you need to do is spend your unconfirmed transaction's output with a sufficient fee. A "sufficiently greedy miner" will process both transactions just to get the fee of the latter.

Comment: Oh I see. I hadn't considered that miners would analyse the queue in such way looking for various threads of dependent transactions and pick the most profitable *threads* over simply picking the most profitable transactions...although it *does* make sense so long as the extra profits on threads more than makes up for the CPU time that they expend analysing the queue to find them.