# Is it possible to recognize conflicting 0-confirmation transactions with the Bitcoin client or other available software?

Tags: transactions, confirmations, fraud

Is there already a way to detect conflicting 0-confirmation transactions? I'm assuming at least one transaction goes to my wallet.

I would expect the client to list the transaction as conflicting but from what I understand from [What does the Bitcoin client do when it receives conflicting transactions?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/730/what-does-the-bitcoin-client-do-when-it-receives-conflicting-transactions) it currently does not do so? Is there any other way available?

Comment: How about conflicting n-confirmation transactions? What does the client do when it finds two heads for the block chain? Any alerts to the user?

Comment: @Thilo: the longest chain always wins. I would expect a block with conflicting transactions to be invalid. Currently there are no user alerts, conflicting transactions will simply not be relayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A merchant can lessen the risk of being defrauded in a race attack (on 0/unconfirmed) by:

- Using an explicit list of peers to connect to (with most of the known IP addresses of miners)
- Not allowing incoming connections (turn off uPnP)

this still leaves the merchant vulnerable to a 51% attack that all transactions below 6 confirmations are subject to but also to the Finney attack and another type of attack even where 2 confirmations is required (as described by vector76 here: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=36788.msg463391#msg463391 )

What you are asking for is a solution that would be useful for merchants who can absorb some risk that comes with accepting a bitcoin transaction at 0/unconfirmed.  Currently there is only a trivial number of merchants that accept bitcoin at a retail establishment.  And thus, no solution provider -- yet.

There is an API to the service http://transactionradar.com which might make it possible to monitor for double spend attempts.

Some useful conversations related to this topic:

- http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=36788.0
- http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=39562.0
- [Has there ever been a successful double spend attack on the Bitcoin network? If not, is it really necessary to wait for confirmations?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/722)
- http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=27899173
- http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=27964471
- [Can bitcoins be counterfeited?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/181/can-bitcoins-be-counterfeited)
- http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=69520

Comment: Thanks for the info and the links. From what I learned it is not possible with the bitcoin client as such because conflicting transactions will not be relayed. Listening to lots of nodes and analyzing their stand like http://transactionradar.com does seems to be what comes closest to detecting conflicting transactions.